# $wpdb get_var issue

Tags: sql

I've been at this for while, but can't figure out why the below isn't working. I have my date saved as a 'MM/DD/YYYY' string.

```
global $wpdb;
$new_day = $day->format("m/d/Y");
$qty = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
    SELECT qty
    FROM $wpdb->specials
    WHERE date = %s
  ",
  $new_day
));
```

Comment: Where does `$day->format("m/d/Y");` come from as it isn't shown as global.

Answer (score 3):

I'll guess that `$wpdb->specials` isn't giving you what you expect. custom tables have to referenced like `$wpdb->prefix . 'specials'`

Comment: thanks Milo. found that because it a custom table, you dont need the `$wpdb` at all.

Comment: @AaronMoodie you don't, however if the table prefix set in  wp-config.php may ever change, you'll want to have that in there.